# How to implement feature like YouTube offline save video in my Android app

Tags: android, video, youtube, offline

How does the YouTube offline feature work? I want to implement this feature in my app. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Youtube Offline Features works in following manner:

1. Youtube app downloads the video.
2. Saves it into youtube app's data directory in encrypted format so other apps can't access it.
3. Encryption is done so that video can not be played by any other apps even if video is extracted from youtube app data directory on rooted Android device.
4. Video is decrypted while playing offline in the youtube app.
5. Video is deleted after a predefined time.

Comment: can I try this in my app for video?

Comment: how??Do I have to download the video,encrypt it and then decrypt it??

Comment: @shriduttkothari Thank you. But how to implement this, is there any library or tutorial available for this.

Comment: did anyone find any solution or tutorial for the same?